# Not indent the same as the first rightarrow

Tags: align

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage[textwidth=8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
C = C_1 + C_2 \Rightarrow f_C = \frac{f_{C_1}f_{C_2}}{\sqrt{{f_{C_1}}^2 + {f_{C_2}}^2}} \\
&\Rightarrow T_C =\sqrt{{T_1}^2+{T_2}^2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}\Large
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify an `&` alignment point in each row of an `align` (or `align*`) environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage[textwidth=8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
C = C_1 + C_2 
&\Rightarrow f_C^{} 
= \frac{f_{C_1}^{} f_{C_2}^{}}{\sqrt{f_{C_1}^2 + f_{C_2}^2}} \\[\jot]
&\Rightarrow T_C^{} =\sqrt{T_1^2+T_2^2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I have done:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Sample text here

$Math~text$
\begin{align*}
C = C_1 + C_2 \Rightarrow f_C = \frac{f_{C_1}f_{C_2}}{\sqrt{{f_{C_1}}^2 + {f_{C_2}}^2}} \ &\Rightarrow T_C =\sqrt{{T_1}^2+{T_2}^2}
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

And it seems to produce a decent output without alignment issues.

[image: Output]

Also, consider using single `$` for math-mode.

Comment: That looks good to me